# bulk upload functionality available in server component model in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I wanted to create bulkupload functionality to upload files and their metadata to sharepoint document library using sharepoint 2010 serverside component model.

Is there any inbuilt functionality is available in Sharepoint 2010 API's??

Comment: need your attention guys

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no such function in server object model. You have to built your own module for that, iterate through all file (and metadata if any) and add it to SharePoint Library.

Comment: If your file is big, it'll affect performance indeed. No other way as far as I know.